# Как создать изогнутую линию с закругленными краями?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Мне нужно создать линию, подобную этому изображению

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но я не знаю, как сдедать закругленные концы линии

```
.line{
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 12.5px #fff;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;}
```

Можете ли вы помочь мне сделать закругленные края линии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to create curved line with rounded edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205862/7394871) от участника  [@Alejandro Arias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11325771/alejandro-arias).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205862/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете добавить два background слоя, чтобы создать круги по краям, как показано ниже:

```css
.line {
  --c:20px; /* control the size */
  
  width: 100px;
  margin-top:-100px;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: solid var(--c) transparent;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-bottom-color:red;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 98%,transparent) left  15% bottom 14%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 98%,transparent) right 15% bottom 14%;
  background-size:var(--c) var(--c);
  background-origin:border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

/* maintain the square ratio */
.line::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line" style="--c:30px;width:200px"></div>
<div class="line" style="--c:40px;width:120px"></div>
<div class="line" style="--c:10px;width:150px"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206001/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```css
#x:after{
content: ';)';
font-family: Courier New;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 125px;
color: red;
-webkit-text-stroke: 10px green;
text-shadow: 0 -125px 0 blue;
filter: drop-shadow(0 -250px 0 gray);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<q>Оцените насколько код SVG короче решения CSS</q>
<br>
<b id='x'>не сильно то и короче,<br>
если хорошо постараться</b>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, `принцип`, та не, у меня и активности из тех полутора лет грубо говоря только обе зимы, да и не люблю оценивать :3 можете копировать, у меня все равно инглиш хромает))

Comment: Так у тебя текста и нет совсем по большому счету. Уберешь его из кода на EnSO текст этот будет явно лишний. И копируй спокойно свой код

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, уломал :3

Answer (score 1):

**Графику лучше создавать в SVG.**

Для создания кривой можно использовать векторный редактор или ещё проще создать кривую с помощью генератора:  **[Quadratic Bezier Curves](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1116)**

Закругление концов кривой делается с помощью атрибута [stroke-linecap="round"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap)

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style="background:dodgerblue;border:1px solid" >  
  <g fill="none" stroke="white"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <path d="M21,60 Q80,115 181,60 " stroke-width="20" /> 
      <path d="M220,60 Q350,115 480,60" stroke-width="30" /> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

*В качестве бонуса:*

### Заполнение строки svg элемента окружностями

для этого необходимо:

- длину черты установить равную нулю – stroke-dasharray=”0, пробел”
- а пробел установить равным ширине строки stroke-width

Итого:
`stroke-dasharray=”0, 30″ stroke-width=”30″`

при таких значениях параметров, строка элемента будет заполнена окружностями

[Подробнее здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1979)

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style="background:dodgerblue;border:1px solid" >  
  <g fill="none" stroke="white"  stroke-linecap="round" >
      <path d="M21,60 Q251,200 481,60" stroke-width="30" stroke-dasharray="0,30" /> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Ещё пример: Визуализация ограничения дорожек бассейна:*

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 600 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style="background:dodgerblue;border:1px solid" >  
  <g fill="none"  stroke="deeppink" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="0,20" >
      <polyline points="10,40 600,40" stroke="deeppink" /> 
        <polyline points="10,140 600,140" stroke="#00FA9A" /> 
         <polyline points="10,240 600,240" stroke="yellow" /> 
          <polyline points="10,340 600,340" stroke="#ADFF2F" />
  </g>
</svg>  
</div>
```